# Python: JSON add object to a list

Tags: python, json, list, object

I have a problem with JSON with my program.
I create object with an interface in Python.
I want to save a list of this object in a file generated by JSON.

JSON makes this:

```
[
    {
        "__class__": "Regle",
        "apartirde": "",
        "prefix": "",
        "postfix": "",
        "extension": "",
        "amorce": "",
        "nomfichier": ""
    }
]
[
    {
        "__class__": "Regle",
        "apartirde": "",
        "prefix": "",
        "postfix": "",
        "extension": "",
        "amorce": "",
        "nomfichier": ""
    }
]
```

But I want something like that :

```
[
    {
        "__class__": "Regle",
        "apartirde": "",
        "prefix": "",
        "postfix": "",
        "extension": "",
        "amorce": "",
        "nomfichier": ""
    },
    {
        "__class__": "Regle",
        "apartirde": "",
        "prefix": "",
        "postfix": "",
        "extension": "",
        "amorce": "",
        "nomfichier": ""
    }
]
```

Because when I want to read this list, JSON prints me this error:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data:

EDIT my code to write:

```
def seria(self, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, class_Regle.Regle):
        return {"__class__": "Regle",
                "apartirde": obj.apartirde,
                "prefix": obj.prefix,
                "postfix": obj.postfix,
                "extension": obj.extension,
                "amorce": obj.amorce,
                "nomfichier": obj.nomfichier}
    raise TypeError(repr(obj) + " n'est pas sérialisable !")

def sauvegarder(self):
    with open(self.fichier,'a', encoding='utf-8') as mon_fichier:
            mon_fichier.json.dump(self.regle, mon_fichier, indent=4, default=self.seria)
```

My code to read:

```
def charger(self):
        with open(self.fichier, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as mon_fichier:
            data =json.load(mon_fichier, object_hook=self.deseria)

def deseria(self, obj_dict):
        if obj_dict["__class__"] == "Regle":
            obj = class_Regle.Regle(obj_dict["apartirde"], obj_dict["prefix"],obj_dict["postfix"],obj_dict["extension"],obj_dict["amorce"],obj_dict["nomfichier"] )
            self.regle.append(obj)
```

Comment: Please share some relevant code

Comment: @Noa it's done :)

Comment: Why are you opening the file in append mode? You should be doing a single `json.dump` after building an object (in this case a list of dictionaries) that represents what you want your json file to be.

Comment: I try tomorow thanks for the answer. I open it in append mode to append at the end of the file i guess. Anyway thanks i will try !

Answer (score 0):

```
def sauvegarder(self):
    with open(self.fichier, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as mon_fichier:
        data =json.load(mon_fichier, object_hook=self.deseria)
    with open(self.fichier,'w', encoding='utf-8') as mon_fichier:
            json.dump(self.regle, mon_fichier, indent=4, default=self.seria)
```

Hello, this is the solution of my problem.
Thank Patrick Haugh, you put me on the right way !